# Connecting Windows Putty with Raspbian SSH

Tags: ssh, putty

With SSH (with port set to 80) turned on my Pi, I am ***able*** to do the following:

- Connect on my pi via `ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 80`
- Connect on my pi via `ssh 192.168... -p 80`
- Ping the external IP address of my pi from my Windows machine

I am trying to connect to my Raspberry Pi with my Windows machine, via PuTTY, but am unable to. Here's what I am ***unable*** to do:

- Ping the 192.168... address of my pi from my Windows machine.

  `Connection timed out`
- From my pi, connect to SSH via the external IP address of the pi.

  `Server unexpectedly closed network connection.`
- Use PuTTY on Windows to connect to my Pi using 192.168..., I get the error:

  `Network error: connection timed out`

Comment: I would suggest switching the port back to 22 rule out other issues first. Second how are the Pi and windows machine connected? are they on the same network. How are you telling putty to use the nonstandard port? ()if you are changing the port port 80 is not the best option as that is the default webserver port. Until you can ping SSH will not work.

Comment: They are on the same network. When I leave it at the default port of `22`I still get the same exact errors and behaviors as in the original post.

Comment: did you restart ssh after changing the port number

Comment: Yes, I restarted it. `shutdown -r now`.

Comment: how are the pi connected directly or through a router? are you running a firewall

Comment: The pi is connected to a router via Wi-Fi and my Windows desktop is connected to the router via ethernet. Turning my firewall off in Windows made no difference. As far as I know, my pi doesn't have a firewall at all.

Comment: can you login to your router and see if the Pi is listed

Comment: At the moment I cannot login to it, but if I can't even connect to my Pi from an external computer, how would it matter whether or not it's listed? What other options is there for debugging?

Comment: because your windows machine is having issues resolving and routing the address hence you can't ping from windows to the Pi. I am assuming that resolving the host is done by the router (as in most cases).

Comment: Okay, I will try to login to the router later, thank you

Comment: Re-reading what you said, I forgot to clarify: I am able to ping my pi from my Windows machine using the pi's external IP address.

Comment: Has that changed then - your question says that this task falls under the "unable to do this" category?

Comment: Check port usage elsewhere as well.